# using pm2 with nodemon gives bad descriptor error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, pm2, nodemon

My project right now is fully ES6+, with import/export and things that do not support by node.js yet, therefore I use nodemon + babel to run it. The package.json looks like:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server/server.js --exec babel-node --presets babel-preset-env"
}
```

And now I am moving to pm2 to manage this app, I have the following ecosystem.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'test:app',
      script: 'npm -- start',
      watch: true,
    },
  ],
};
```

This brings up the app but with errors like:

```
3|your-tab | Error: EBADF: bad file descriptor, uv_pipe_open
3|your-tab |     at Object._forkChild (child_process.js:115:5)
3|your-tab |     at Object.setupChildProcessIpcChannel (internal/process/main_thread_only.js:117:30)
3|your-tab |     at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:135:23)
3|your-tab |     at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:739:3)
3|your-tab | child_process.js:115
3|your-tab |   p.open(fd);
```

I think my ecosystem file is wrong, but how do I fix it so that I can run pm2 + babel + nodemon?

Answer (score 0):

The **script** option for the app in the ecosystem configuration has to be a path that exists.

There are some ways to go about your ecosystem configuration for your application.

### Using the default interpreter (node)

You can write a node script that starts your app and use that for the script option. You probably will be using "child_process" node module for that.

### Using a bash as the interpreter

You can configure the interpreter for the application to bash. Then write a bash script to run your application.

Say you have a `run-yap` bash shell script containing:

```
npm start
```

The ecosystem configuration file should look like so:

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
       script: "run-yap",
       name: "yap",
       interpreter: "bash",
    }
  ]
}
```